# Change Detect not working in directive event ouput in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, events, directive

I use this directive. However, on the setAddress event output, no changes are detected in my component. The view is not updated. I d'ont understand.

For test, if i remove the google.maps.event.addListener to replace by a simple setTimeout to call invokeEvent. It works.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[googleplace]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(input)' : 'onInputChange()'
  }
})
export class GoogleplaceDirective  {
  @Output() setAddress: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  modelValue:any;
  autocomplete:any;
  private _el:HTMLElement;


  constructor(el: ElementRef,private model:NgModel) {
    this._el = el.nativeElement;
    this.modelValue = this.model;
    var input = this._el;
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', ()=> {
      var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      this.invokeEvent(place);
    });
  }

  invokeEvent(place:Object) {
    this.setAddress.emit(place);
  }


  onInputChange() {
  }
}
```

In my component view

```
<input type="text" class="validation-address-input" style="margin-top: 100px;" [value]="form.customerAddress"
               (setAddress)="setCustomStartLocation($event)" googleplace>
```

In my component

```
/**
     *
     * @param place
     */
    setCustomStartLocation(place: Object) {
        this.currentStep = 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handler for `place_changed` is running outside angular zone. You need to run it like this:

```
constructor(..., private zone: NgZone) {
  ...
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', ()=> {
    var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    this.zone.run(() => this.invokeEvent(place)); // run inside angular zone
  });
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks

Comment: since event emitter updates value on the parent component regardless of zone it runs in, the other approach could be to just inject `app:ApplicationRef` and call `app.tick()`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to inject `ApplicationRef` and call `tick()` method to run change detection cycle:

```
export class GoogleplaceDirective  {

  constructor(private app: ApplicationRef, ...) {
    ...
  }

  invokeEvent(place:Object) {
    this.setAddress.emit(place);
    this.app.tick(); <-----------------------------------
  }
```

This is essentially what zone is doing:

```
_this._zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe({
    next: function () {
        _this._zone.run(function () {
            _this.tick();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If something will be initialized during update on the parent component then this something can go wrong during the next action. And you will have to run detectChanges or tick again

Comment: @yurzui, interesting, can you maybe create a plunker to show it?

Comment: That is why angular includes `this.zone.run` for subscribe

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CgkColxdjdtnFFzhGXHm?p=preview Сhoose something then click on `Change address to dd` button. Then force update

Comment: @yurzui, thanks, that's an interesting behavior, do you know the underlying cause for that?

Comment: `addEventListener` is being called outside angular zone

Comment: @yurzui, I understand that, I'm thinking why the `app.tick()` is **not** triggered the next time the click event is triggered `<button (click)="address = 'dd'">` and the `address` is updated

Comment: That's because when template is initialized during the `app.tick()`  `addEventListener` for `button (click)="address = 'dd'` is being called outside angular zone. So when you click on this button it will be running outside angular zone

Comment: See zone primer https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F5Ug0jcrm031vhSMJEOgp1l-Is-Vf0UCNDY-LsQtAIY/edit# `When async work gets scheduled, the callback function will execute in the same zone as the zone which existed at the time of invoking the async API. This allows the zone to be tracked across many async invocations.`