# Angular form don't validate when address is selected

Tags: forms, angular, validation

The form uses google places api to get adresses but clicking on a adress (or selecting it with the keybord) will not trigger a revalidation of the form?

https://plnkr.co/edit/LgEn9t0X2h6BTHGwyJOW?p=preview

I update the value with

```
this.registrationForm.patchValue({ adress: adress.formatted_address});
```

and have tried to trigger the validation manually using the methods

```
this.registrationForm.markAsDirty(true);
```

and

```
this.registrationForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

but cant get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `place_changed` event is fired outside angular zone i would suggest we should call `zone.run()` like

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

...
google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
    const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    this.zone.run(() => this.invokeEvent(place));
```

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4Srx8s1SBZuPYyZrKqF6?p=preview)**

See also

- [Change Detect not working in directive event ouput in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086130/change-detect-not-working-in-directive-event-ouput-in-angular-2)

Comment: ah.. I was assuming that the form update using patchValue would trigger the form to revalidate.. Thx! :)