# angular view not updating when data changes

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript

Am working on a chat application  using NativeScript with Angular using a Firebase plugin.
Am using the firebase event listener to listen for changes on a path like this:

```
firebase.addValueEventListener( (result) => {
  for(var key in result.value){
    this.posts.push(result.value[key].Message);
  }
  this.messages = this.posts;
  //am using this.messges to update the view
  this.posts=[];


  }, '/forum/messages');
}
```

The problem is when I send a message from my end the view gets updated but when someone sends a message from their end the messages array changes but I don't see it unless I restart the application.
What could be causing this.

Comment: Can you check output of `NgZone.isInAngularZone()` if put it front of `this.message`?

Comment: in front how? can you illustrate?

Comment: Of course. For example http://take.ms/euvJl

Comment: @yurzui its false

Comment: Try running code inside angular zone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086130/change-detect-not-working-in-directive-event-ouput-in-angular-2/44086281#44086281

Comment: @yurzui thanks but its a bit confusing...can you help me with an illustration?

Answer (score 5):

when you listen on the firebase event listener it run your code outside the angular zone. so basically you need to assign values to your variable inside NgZone.

Also running changeDetection cycle forcefully with the help of `ChangeDetectionRef` using `cd.detectChanges()` guaranties that changes reflected successfully. but you might not need to do this. do this only `zone.run` doesn't work alone.

for example

```
import {
    NgZone,
    ChangeDetectorRef
} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./home-common.css", "./home.css"]
})
export class HomeComponent{
    messages=[];
    constructor(
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private zone: NgZone
    ) {
        firebase.addValueEventListener( (result) => {


          for(var key in result.value){
            this.posts.push(result.value[key].Message);
          }
          this.zone.run(() => {
              this.messages = this.posts;
              this.cd.detectChanges();
          })

          //am using this.messges to update the view
          this.posts=[];


          }, '/forum/messages');
        }
    }
}
```